# Collecting neighboring vertices graphx

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm trying to collect all the neighboring vertices given one vertex. But I am getting this error. An example of one vertex is (1,"some string")

```
val direction: EdgeDirection = 
graph.collectNeighborIds(direction).lookup(1)
```

Here is my error:

```
<console>:50: error: type mismatch;
found   : Seq[Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId]]
required: org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeDirection
     graph.collectNeighborIds(direction).lookup(1)
                                               ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not make any sense. Try something like

```
val direction: EdgeDirection = EdgeDirection.Out
val neighbourToVertexOne = graph.collectNeighborIds(direction).lookup(1)
```

Then do whatever you want to do with the resultant Array.